# Get-ADGroup specific ou

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2019

My Code:

```
$ADGroupList = (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -searchbase "OU=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,DC=local" -Properties *).Name
```

The error its returning:

```
Get-ADGroup : Directory object not found
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Ordner, Gruppen, Rechte.ps1:31 char:17
+ ... roupList = (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -searchbase "OU=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,D ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDir 
  ectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Can someone help  me? I have no clue why its not working.

Comment: And as aside, do not ask for **ALL** properties if you only want the Name. As this is returned by default, you can leave out `-Properties *` alltogether

Comment: try this  $ADGroupList = (Get-AdGroup -filter * -searchbase  "OU=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,DC=local" | select name -ExpandProperty name)

Comment: It is possible that `OU=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,DC=local` may not exist. If it is a container rather than an OU, it will have path `CN=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,DC=local`. You can run `Get-ADObject 'OU=Staedte,DC=dmamgt,DC=local'` to know if it exists.

Comment: Run `Get-ADObject -searchbase 'DC=dmamgt,DC=local' -searchscope onelevel -filter "name -like '*Staedte*'"` to determine the actual path you should be searching.